# How can I use data from one table to create new rows in a second table when the two tables don't have any shared column names

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `leads` and a table called `call_logs`, each with various columns but only two columns from leads and three columns from call_logs are relevant.

I need to insert new rows in the `call_logs` table for each row in the `leads` table where the owner is "12345". The "owner" column values in the leads table need to be entered into the "user" column of the call_logs table. Likewise, the "lead_id" column values in the leads table need to be entered into the "lead" column of the call_logs table.

Lastly I need to update the call_started value for each newly created row with today's date.

So the leads table data:

| owner | lead_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 54321 | John | Smith |
| 43212 | 43928 | Jane | Doe |

Should insert into the call_logs table:

| user | lead | call_started | call_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 54321 | 2022-05-02 10:50:43 |  |
| 82919 | 73261 | 2022-04-21 09:32:12 | "this is pre-existing data" |

I have tried variations of:

```
UPDATE call_logs cl 
JOIN leads l ON l.owner = cl.user 
SET cl.call_started = CURDATE(), cl.user = 12345 
WHERE l.owner = 12345
```

```
UPDATE call_logs
LEFT JOIN leads ON call_logs.user = leads.owner AND call_logs.lead = leads.lead_id
SET call_started = CURDATE()
```

In this snippet I attempted to abandon the UPDATE JOIN idea and just create new rows and then update the call_started value in a separate snippet.

```
INSERT INTO call_logs (user, lead)  
SELECT owner, lead_id
  FROM leads
 WHERE owner = 12345
```

The first two sql snippets ran but did not change anything and the last snippet gave me an error stating

> Field 'call_sid' doesn't have a default value

The `call_sid` field is the actual first column in the `call_logs` table but is irrelevant for my purposes. Any other fields in the newly created rows in the call_logs table can have null values and it will not affect what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 different things:

1. Set a default value for the column **call_sid**. This way you don´t need to change your query.
2. If you don´t want to set a default value, and if that value it is not important (be carefull with that, it may be important for somer other process), then you can change your query to:

   ```
   INSERT INTO call_logs (user, lead, call_sid)  
   SELECT owner, lead_id, 0
   FROM leads
   WHERE owner = 12345
   ```

Comment: @ttrudo08:  Where you can use any value, in stead of `0`, for the new value of `call_sid`.  The value chosen would be the default value that you would have set when you used option 1.

Comment: This is only going to be ran in a test environment with a local host and copy of the database so setting a default value shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for the input. It's working now @nacho